# ORACLE SQL Count and Join Issue

Tags: join, count

ok so i need to count how many times the "resource_ID" has occurred less than 3 times in my table, and then link the Resource DESCRIPTION From another table.

so far i have got

```
Select Resource_hire.Resource_ID, count(resource_ID) as Times_Used  

from RESOURCE_HIRE

Group by resource_ID

HAVING COUNT(*)< 3;
```

But when i add

```
SELECT RESOURCE_INVENTORY.DESCRIPTION, RESOURCE_HIRE.RESOURCE_ID

FROM RESOURCE_HIRE, RESOURCE_INVENTORY

WHERE (RESOURCE_HIRE.RESOURCE_ID = RESOURCE_INVENTORY.R_ID)

INNER JOIN (Select Resource_hire.Resource_ID, count(resource_ID)
from RESOURCE_HIRE

Group by resource_ID

HAVING COUNT(*)< 3;)
```

i Get  SQL command not properly ended

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the joins in a wrong manner.

Try this:

```
  SELECT ri.DESCRIPTION, rh.RESOURCE_ID
    FROM RESOURCE_HIRE rh
         INNER JOIN (Select Resource_hire.Resource_ID, count(resource_ID)
                       from RESOURCE_HIRE
                      Group by resource_ID
                     having COUNT(*)< 3;) rh
         ON (rh.RESOURCE_ID = ri.R_ID)
```

You cannot use the `JOIN` keyword and joining in the `WHERE` clause at the same time.

More on joins on [Oracle Docs](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&sqi=2&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm&ei=e8SHUdCbJo-fiAe224GgBA&usg=AFQjCNHjcXQ7h7vCqF38xFZlB030a020uw&sig2=Wf4bNjRGvKnq5OY2uK0Sxw&bvm=bv.45960087,d.aGc).